# Print memory block when dropped into ldb

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I am dropped into the ldb with the message

> Heap exhausted during garbage collection: 0 bytes available, 16
>   requested.

The message itself is clear. Though I have a hard time figuring out where my memory is going to. I tried to use the `ldb` command `dump` but I always get

> invalid Lisp-level address:

**How can I use dump** and is there a way to print a large block of used memory in a human readable way to improve the understanding of what is cluttering the memory?

E.g.

```
ldb> dump magicKeyWords
#0xFFFF OBJECTTYPEA
#0xFFFE OBJECTTYPEA
....
```